# Is there a way to edit my email subscription settings across all my SE accounts?

Tags: discussion, email, subscription

Is there a way to do this globally rather than having to do it for each account separately?

For example, I would like to adjust settings globally regarding notifications of items in my inboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already across all your associated **sites/communities** on SE:

> [image]

If you mean across all your **accounts** (as in different login, e.g. sock accounts)  then no, it's not possible since each account is on its own and should NOT be linked together.

Comment: Many thanks. D'y'know, I'd never noticed those words "These settings affect" before. Had I, I wouldn't have asked. As for my use of the word "accounts", I was following company usage for example [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/7431540/ruffle?tab=accounts) where the word "account" is used to mean a membership of a subsite such as Law.SE, Mathematics.SE, etc.

Comment: @ruffle well, didn't you notice that changing on one site affected all others? Anyway no harm done. Cheers! :)

Comment: No, I didn't. I just kept getting unwanted emails after I thought I'd stopped them. I do have more than one global account at SE, but not for any untoward purpose.